# Check if form parent is valid in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

There is any wey to know if is the parent form is valid. This is the code. It always throw: "You cannot call isValid() on a form that is not bound.". Thank you!!

```
class FoorType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('field_1') // Required
            ->add('field_2') // Required
            ->add('field_3') // Required
            ->add('bar', 'my_custom_form_type') // Not required
    }
} 

class MyCustomFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_BIND, function(DataEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();

            if ($form->getParent()->isValid()) {
                // Do smething...
            }
        });
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_custom_form_type';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi found the solution!!

Use getParent() in addEventListener:

```
$builder->getParent()->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_BIND, function(DataEvent $event)   
{
     // Code
});
```